# Creating app with min SDK level 8 and target SDK level 15?

Tags: android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-support-library, android-2.3-gingerbread

**Background:**

I'm working on re-working an older app of mine to make use of the action bar, however I want to of course still hit a quite large focus group being 2.3.3 users.

**Problem:**

My app works fine on my newer Jelly Bean Phone, but crashes on my older GingerBread phone with NoSuchMethodException at "getActionBar()... etc.

I know this is happening because the phone doesn't support it..but I **don't understand why because I am using android-support-v4.jar**, and I can see the methods and code fine without any compilation errors.

**My research:**

I've read other posts and they say change your minSdkVersion to 11 and it should work fine, *but I want support for older devices*.

I've also used the amazing actionbarsherlock library in a previous project, and didn't have this problem...

**Details:**

In my android SDK file I have

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17" android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

**I'm using Android Studios, so I've set the build target of the project to be 4.2.2 (I'm not sure if this is right)..**

My android manifest file also has:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

and I have 2 folders in my res folder - one being values and values-v11

values contains this in its styles file:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
</resources>
```

and values-v11 contains this in its style file:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light" />
<style name="MenuTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar" />
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

change "getActionBar()" to "getSupportActionBar()" and it should work.
Also, make sure your Activity is subclassing either SherlockActivity or SherlockFragmentActivity.

getActionBar() was added in API level 11, ActionBarSherlock adds the getSupportActionBar() method for backwards compatibility.